# How to integrate an external API in web-hook integration on a repository?

Tags: github, github-api, webhooks

I am using a Web-hooks services in GitHub.

Whenever an event occurs on my repository, that will notify on ngrok server.

I Want to call my API whenever an event happens in my repository.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to build a small proxy service which will accept the webhook delivery from GitHub and translate it to an call of your API. You can't change how the payload of the webhook delivery looks in GitHub, you you need to make that change in a small proxy service and then call the API using the information from the webhook delivery.